# Android: Start a new activity by onClick on LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

[Click here to see xml result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ3F9.png)
**I'm trying to access edit_profile_fragment by clicking on LinearLayout 
 
main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/editProfile"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/location" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:text="My address"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp">

                    <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/arrow_expand" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp">

                <View

                    style="@style/Divider"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

```
public LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editProfile);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AccountActivity.this,EditProfileFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return linearLayout;
    }
```

**As you can see, I have a clickable LinearLayout, but it doesn't start new activity or fragment when I click! 
Thank you in advanced.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this peace of code inside `onClick` method.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager();
transaction.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.editProfile, new EditProfileFragment())
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Do you ever call method `getLinearLayout()` before clicking on `LinearLayout`? Second thing - you have multiple layouts "covering" your `LinearLayout` so you need to set their properties (all children of your Linear) as `android:clickable="false"` and for your `LinearLayout` set `android:clickable="true"` and finally the third thing: you have a lot of nested layouts which is terrible practise. You should flattern it for sure (consider `ConstraintLayout`) but it's out of your question..